# Multirow axis labels with nested grouping variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, axis-labels

I would like the levels of two different nested grouping variables to appear on separate lines below the plot, and not in the legend. What I have right now is this code:

```
data <- read.table(text = "Group Category Value
    S1 A   73
    S2 A   57
    S1 B   7
    S2 B   23
    S1 C   51
    S2 C   87", header = TRUE)

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Category, y = Value, fill = Group)) + 
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge') +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(Value, "%")), 
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), vjust = -0.25)
```

[image]

What I would like to have is something like this:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: To actually put the labels outside the panel as you picture will require some serious `grid` graphics wizardry. However, if you can accept having them inside the panel, `geom_text` can give you a solution.

Comment: I'm on my phone, but this question has been asked several times. I'm sure a duplicate could be found by an enterprising Googler.

Comment: @joran I can't find the duplicate question. SO I hope i haven't over-complicated the solution.

Comment: Thanks Frank, but that's not what I was looking for. Fantastic job agstudy, I also tried to find the duplicate (again, without success) and use Drew Steen suggestion and it kind of worked, but your solution is perfect!

Comment: `xmax = Inf` should do the trick for annotation_custom (better would be `annotate("segment", ...)` or `annotate("hline", ...)`)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can create a custom element function for `axis.text.x`.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

## create some data with asymmetric fill aes to generalize solution 
data <- read.table(text = "Group Category Value
                   S1 A   73
                   S2 A   57
                   S3 A   57
                   S4 A   57
                   S1 B   7
                   S2 B   23
                   S3 B   57
                   S1 C   51
                   S2 C   57
                   S3 C   87", header=TRUE)

# user-level interface 
axis.groups = function(groups) {
  structure(
    list(groups=groups),
    ## inheritance since it should be a element_text
    class = c("element_custom","element_blank")  
  )
}
# returns a gTree with two children: 
# the categories axis
# the groups axis
element_grob.element_custom <- function(element, x,...)  {
  cat <- list(...)[[1]]
  groups <- element$group
  ll <- by(data$Group,data$Category,I)
  tt <- as.numeric(x)
  grbs <- Map(function(z,t){
    labs <- ll[[z]]
    vp = viewport(
             x = unit(t,'native'), 
             height=unit(2,'line'),
             width=unit(diff(tt)[1],'native'),
             xscale=c(0,length(labs)))
    grid.rect(vp=vp)
    textGrob(labs,x= unit(seq_along(labs)-0.5,
                                'native'),
             y=unit(2,'line'),
             vp=vp)
  },cat,tt)
  g.X <- textGrob(cat, x=x)
  gTree(children=gList(do.call(gList,grbs),g.X), cl = "custom_axis")
}

## # gTrees don't know their size 
grobHeight.custom_axis = 
  heightDetails.custom_axis = function(x, ...)
  unit(3, "lines")

## the final plot call
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=Category, y=Value, fill=Group)) + 
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(width=0.9),stat='identity') +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste(Value, "%")),
            position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25)+
  theme(axis.text.x = axis.groups(unique(data$Group)),
        legend.position="none")
```

Comment: you might need to define a heightDetails method to avoid problems with vertical justification

Answer (score 78):

The `strip.position` argument in `facet_wrap()` and `switch` argument in `facet_grid()` since *ggplot2* 2.2.0 now makes the creation of a simple version of this plot fairly straightforward via faceting.  To give the plot the uninterrupted look, set the `panel.spacing` to 0.

Here's the example using the dataset with a different number of Groups per Category from @agtudy's answer.

- I used `scales = "free_x"` to drop the extra Group from the Categories that don't have it, although this won't always be desirable.
- The `strip.position = "bottom"` argument moves the facet labels to the bottom.  I removed the strip background all together with `strip.background`, but I could see that leaving the strip rectangle would be useful in some situations.
- I used `width = 1` to make the bars within each Category touch - they'd have spaces between them by default.

I also use `strip.placement` and `strip.background` in `theme` to get the strips on the bottom and remove the strip rectangle.

The code for versions of ggplot2_2.2.0 or newer:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Group, y = Value, fill = Group)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1) +
    geom_text(aes(label = paste(Value, "%")), vjust = -0.25) +
    facet_wrap(~Category, strip.position = "bottom", scales = "free_x") +
    theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"), 
         strip.background = element_blank(),
         strip.placement = "outside")
```

[image]

You could use `space= "free_x"` in `facet_grid()` if you wanted all the bars to be the same width regardless of how many Groups per Category.  Note that this uses `switch = "x"` instead of `strip.position`.  You also might want to change the label of the x axis; I wasn't sure what it should be, maybe Category instead of Group?

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Group, y = Value, fill = Group)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1) +
    geom_text(aes(label = paste(Value, "%")), vjust = -0.25) +
    facet_grid(~Category, switch = "x", scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") +
    theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"), 
         strip.background = element_blank(),
         strip.placement = "outside") + 
    xlab("Category")
```

[image]

**Older code versions**

The code for ggplot2_2.0.0, when this feature was first introduced, was a little different.  I've saved it below for posterity:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Group, y = Value, fill = Group)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    geom_text(aes(label = paste(Value, "%")), vjust = -0.25) +
    facet_wrap(~Category, switch = "x", scales = "free_x") +
    theme(panel.margin = unit(0, "lines"), 
         strip.background = element_blank())
```

Comment: The effect is gorgeous and solution so simple. Although I don't think it would be fair to change the accepted answer right now. Great answer nonetheless.

Answer (score 14):

I know this question is old but i would like to intoduce the cleanest way to do this with `ggh4x`

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

data <- read.table(text = "Group Category Value
    S1 A   73
    S2 A   57
    S1 B   7
    S2 B   23
    S1 C   51
    S2 C   87", header = TRUE)

# Only one more line of code with the function 'guide_axis_nested'
# and changing the data from x axis to interaction(Group,Category, sep = "!")

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = interaction(Group,Category, sep = "!"), y = Value, fill = Group)) + 
  geom_col(position = 'dodge', show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(Value, "%")), 
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), vjust = -0.25) +
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis_nested(delim = "!"), name = "Category")
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

A very simple solution which gives a similar (though not identical) result is to use faceting.  The downside is that the Category label is above rather than below.

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=Group, y=Value, fill=Group)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat="identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste(Value, "%")), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25) + 
  facet_grid(. ~ Category) + 
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image: Using faceting to provide secondary label]

Comment: how would you change this if not all groups had all categories?

Comment: old comment, but you can `drop = F` to ensure that the space is left for any missing categories

Answer (score 7):

An alternative to agstudy's method is to edit the gtable and insert an "axis" calculated by ggplot2,

```
p <- ggplot(data=data, aes(x=Category, y=Value, fill=Group)) + 
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(width=0.9),stat='identity') +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste(Value, "%")),
            position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25)

axis <- ggplot(data=data, aes(x=Category, y=Value, colour=Group)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=Group, y=0),
            position=position_dodge(width=0.9))

annotation <- gtable_filter(ggplotGrob(axis), "panel", trim=TRUE)
annotation[["grobs"]][[1]][["children"]][c(1,3)] <- NULL #only keep textGrob

library(gtable)
g <- ggplotGrob(p)
gtable_add_grobs <- gtable_add_grob # let's use this alias
g <- gtable_add_rows(g, unit(1,"line"), pos=4)
g <- gtable_add_grobs(g, annotation, t=5, b=5, l=4, r=4)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Comment: +10! Nice idea to create the `textGrob` by ggplot2( avoid viewports low level). Why are you using an alias? and you can also remove the legend ( no more need).

Comment: i believe it should be named `gtable_add_grobs` for consistency with add_rows, etc., and if the change is made in the future all these previous answers would have to be edited.

Answer (score 4):

@agstudy already answered this question and I'm going to use it myself, but if you'd accept something uglier, but simpler, this is what I came with before his answer:

```
data <- read.table(text = "Group Category Value
    S1 A   73
    S2 A   57
    S1 B   7
    S2 B   23
    S1 C   51
    S2 C   87", header=TRUE)

p <- ggplot(data=data, aes(x=Category, y=Value, fill=Group))
p + geom_bar(position = 'dodge') +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste(Value, "%")), position=position_dodge(width=0.9),   vjust=-0.25) +
  geom_text(colour="darkgray", aes(y=-3, label=Group),  position=position_dodge(width=0.9), col=gray) +
  theme(legend.position = "none", 
    panel.background=element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
    axis.line.x = element_line(colour = "white"),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank()) +
  annotate("segment", x = 0, xend = Inf, y = 0, yend = 0)
```

Which will give us:

[image]

Comment: Nice solution :), it might be a little better if you were to just include the code which is specific for the problem only. Additional code can often confuse people. :)

Comment: You'll have to replace geom_bar(position = 'dodge') with geom_bar(position= 'dodge', stat='identity') to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution using a package I'm working on for grouped bar charts ([ggNestedBarChart](https://github.com/davedgd/ggNestedBarChart)):

```
data <- read.table(text = "Group Category Value
                   S1 A   73
                   S2 A   57
                   S3 A   57
                   S4 A   57
                   S1 B   7
                   S2 B   23
                   S3 B   57
                   S1 C   51
                   S2 C   57
                   S3 C   87", header = TRUE)

devtools::install_github("davedgd/ggNestedBarChart")
library(ggNestedBarChart)
library(scales)

p1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Category, y = Value/100, fill = Category), stat = "identity") +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(vars(Category, Group), strip.position = "top", scales = "free_x", nrow = 1) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 13) +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
        strip.background = element_rect(color = "black", size = 0, fill = "grey92"),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "grey"),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA, size = 0),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        legend.position = "none") + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(mult = c(0, .1)), labels = percent) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(Value, "%")), position = position_stack(0.5), color = "white", fontface = "bold")

ggNestedBarChart(p1)

ggsave("p1.png", width = 10, height = 5)
```

[image: example plot]

Note that ggNestedBarChart can group as many levels as necessary and isn't limited to just two (i.e., Category and Group in this example). For instance, using data(mtcars):

[image: deep nesting/grouping]

Code for this example is on the GitHub page.

Comment: Hi could you please help me to install your ggNestedBarChart package as I'm trying to use it but I cannot install it.

Comment: Happy to help with that. The instructions above will work, but only if you install devtools first. Try running this before the instructions above:

`install.packages("devtools")`

I'd also install the other dependencies like scales to ensure you have them:

`install.packages("devtools", "scales", "ggplot2")`

Comment: Thank you so much, your help is appreciated. I installed the  package and used the examples and it worked perfectly. but for my data when I use ```ggNestedBarChart(p1)``` , I get this error: ```Error in while (nrow(buildReplacementFacet) + 1 < j * 2) buildReplacementFacet <- rbind(buildReplacementFacet,  : 
  argument is of length zero```  Can you please help me with this? Many thanks. Its really nice packge and do exactly what I want. Thank you so much for developing it.

Comment: @MarwahAl-kaabi, Ah, I see: That sounds a bit more complex to diagnose and potentially an issue with the package code. Would you mind opening an issue on GitHub with as much detail as you can provide, and then I can help you diagnose from there?