# grouping bars in bar-plot without using facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I want to group the bars in a stacked barplot according to the values in another factor-variable. However, I want to do this without using facets.

[my data in long format](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4vhv9lgjg4ifh4j/nlmelt.txt)

I want to group the stacked bars according the `afk` variable. The normal stacked bar plot can be made with:

```
ggplot(nl.melt, aes(x=naam, y=perc, fill=stemmen)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=.7) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()
```

which gives an alfabetically ordered barplot:
[image]

I tried to group them by using `x=reorder(naam,afk)` in the `aes`. But that didn't work. Also using `group=afk` does not have the desired effect.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Jaap, for some reason I can´t copy your `dput`ed data, is it correct? It seems that some quotes are missing.

Comment: @CarlosCinelli I've updated the question with a link to the data.

Comment: I think this has what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060949/ggplot2-multiple-sub-groups-of-a-bar-chart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reorder` should work but the problem is you're trying to re-order by a factor. You need to be explicit on how you want to use that information. You can either use

```
nl.melt$naam <- reorder(nl.melt$naam, as.numeric(nl.melt$afk))
```

or

```
nl.melt$naam <- reorder(nl.melt$naam, as.character(nl.melt$afk), FUN=min)
```

depending on whether you want to sort by the existing levels of `afk` or if you want to sort alphabetically by the levels of `afk`.

After running that and re-running the ggplot code, i get

[image: updated bar chart]

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to @MrFlick's approach (based on the answer @CarlosCinelli linked to) is:

```
ggplot(nl.melt, aes(x=interaction(naam,afk), y=perc, fill=stemmen)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=.7) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()
```

which gives:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

R tends to see the order of levels as a property of the data rather than a property of the graph.  Try reordering the data itself before calling the plotting commands.  Try running:

```
nl.melt$naam <- reorder(nl.melt$naam, nl.melt$afk)
```

Then run your `ggplot` code.  Or use other ways of reordering your factor levels in `naam`.