# Bar chart for factorial designs in R

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I'm currently trying to create a clustered bar chart using ggplot2. It's basically just mean response times for a 2x2x2 factorial design. The three factors are load, compatibility and salience. I'm having a hard time jamming the third factor (salience) in there though. It shouldn't be a stacked graph though

This is what I currently have

```
bar+stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "bar", position = "dodge") + 
+ stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal, geom = "errorbar", position = position_dodge(width = 0.90), width = 0.2)+
+ labs(x = "Compatibility", y = "Mean RT", fill = "Load")
```

Here's a small sample of the data I'm trying to graph:

```
     ID   load   comp           sal           rt                     
1     1   High   Incompatible   Non_Salient   787 
2     1   Low    Compatible     Salient       754
3     2   High   Incompatible   Salient       654
```

I've seen graphs like these numerous times before but I have no idea how to get ggplot2 to display three independent variables at the same time.

I've tried splitting the graphs by adding

```
+ facet_wrap( ~ sal)
```

but that doesn't work either. It just says "Invalid argument to unary operator"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Would you be able to provide reproducible data? You will be likely to receive more help when you can supply the data. You can type `dput(yourdata)` in your R Console. You will see some texts which are your data. You can copy and paste them in your question.

Comment: Also could you add an example of what you are hoping to accomplish. I'm having trouble visualizing what your expected output looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the kind of plot you are looking for? [image]

I used the [Wii data](http://www.sagepub.com/dsur/study/DSUR%20Data%20Files/Chapter%2012/Wii.dat) from the book "Discovering Statistics Using R", which is in a similar format to yours.

```
structure(list(athlete = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("Athlete", "Non-Athlete"), class = "factor"), 
stretch = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No Stretching", "Stretching"
), class = "factor"), wii = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Playing Wii", 
"Watching Wii"), class = "factor"), injury = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
6L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 
9L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 10L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 0L)), 
.Names = c("athlete", "stretch", "wii", "injury"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -120L))
```

Here is how to produce the plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(Hmisc)
ggplot(data=Wii, aes(x=stretch, y=injury, fill=wii)) + 
  facet_wrap(~athlete) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "bar", position = "dodge") + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal, geom = "errorbar", position = position_dodge(width = 0.90), width = 0.2)
```

Comment: That's as close as I got as well. I actually wanted to create a graph that merged those two graphs into one graph. So the x-axis would contain 2 nested variables and the clustered bars the third. Thanks for the effort though. This will do just as nicely.

Comment: Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060949/ggplot2-multiple-sub-groups-of-a-bar-chart