# Label nested factor levels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data are included below via `dput` and look like this:

```
> head(dat)
     General      Covariate       Beta     SE Season
1  Intercept      Intercept -4.0673077 0.0499 Summer
2 Reggedness SlopeVar_30Log  0.1835911 0.0130 Summer
3  Elevation         Ele_30  0.6194081 0.0186 Summer
4      Slope      Slope_500  2.3549884 0.0527 Summer
5    SlopeSq    Slope_500Sq -0.6729443 0.0326 Summer
6     CanCov    CanCov_1000 -0.3879034 0.0234 Summer
```

I have 8 estimates for `Summer` and 9 for `Winter`.

With these data I can make the following figure. In this instance I have `General` as the x-axis and each value within `General` is plotted on a single line and dodged.  However, I want to label the multiple values of `General` by the `Covariate` name. Each level of `General` has two levles of  `Covariate`

```
ggplot(dat [dat $General != "Intercept",], aes(y = Beta, x = General, color = Season)) + 
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(0.6), size = 5)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Beta-SE, ymax=Beta+SE),width = 0.6, size = 1.2 , position=position_dodge(0.6))
```

[image]

If I simply change the x-axis to `Covariate` (as below) then each level is on a separate line, except where the levels are identical as with `Ele_30`.

```
ggplot(dat [dat $General != "Intercept",], aes(y = Beta, x = Covariate, color = Season)) + 
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(0.6), size = 3)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Beta-SE, ymax=Beta+SE),width = 0.6, size = 1.2 , position=position_dodge(0.6))+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=30, hjust=1))
```

[image]

Is it possible to plot each level of `General` on the same vertical line (as in the first figure above), but label each point according to `Covariate` (like in the bottom figure)? Said differently, I want the points plotted as in plot one, and a label under each dodged point that corresponds to `Covariate`.

Thanks for any help.

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- structure(list(General = structure(c(3L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 
4L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 9L), .Label = c("CanCov", 
"Elevation", "Intercept", "NDVI", "Reggedness", "Slope", "SlopeSq", 
"Solar", "Snow"), class = "factor"), Covariate = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 
15L), .Label = c("Intercept", "SlopeVar_30Log", "VMR_30Log", 
"Ele_30", "Slope_500", "Slope_100", "Slope_500Sq", "Slope_100Sq", 
"CanCov_1000", "CanCov_30", "NDVI_MeanTin_1000", "NDVI_MeanAmp_1000", 
"RadSumm_30", "AspectCos_30", "SnowSWE_1000"), class = "factor"), 
    Beta = c(-4.06730774504316, 0.183591094124286, 0.61940812155272, 
    2.35498841169247, -0.672944306628242, -0.387903359930857, 
    -0.815906730978726, -0.351201997266259, -5.06483998950688, 
    0.454499369654063, -0.337997523846132, 2.10010144558015, 
    0.251723125039171, -0.281294023525884, -1.02515594862923, 
    -0.46350259164822, -0.498134174074173), SE = c(0.0499, 0.013, 
    0.0186, 0.0527, 0.0326, 0.0234, 0.0152, 0.0107, 0.113, 0.0126, 
    0.0255, 0.0427, 0.0228, 0.0222, 0.0271, 0.0197, 0.033), Season = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L), .Label = c("Summer", "Winter"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("General", 
"Covariate", "Beta", "SE", "Season"), row.names = c(NA, 17L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You can use  `x = interaction(Covariate,General)` or `...+ facet_grid(~General,scales = "free_x")`

Comment: Cool tip.  Nonetheless, each point is plotted on a separate vertical line when there are multiple levels of `Covariate`. Is it possible to have each point on a single vertical line and then `dodge`-ed?

Comment: The second part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060949/ggplot2-multiple-sub-groups-of-a-bar-chart/20073020#20073020) perhaps? Or maybe [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165863/ggplot2-labels-of-grouping-values-below-the-plot), which provides several alternative of multi-row labels.

Comment: Are there cases where your factors `season` and `covariate` have both two variables. Then there should be 4 points "doged" together, right?

Comment: @Jimbou and Henrik, thanks for the helpful comments.  Given the links that Henrick provided maybe this should be marked as a duplicate...?  Or Jimbou, do you want to post your first comment as an answer?