# How to create a plot by two subgroups using interaction() in ggplot (combination of several plots)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create plots by two subgroups, just like in the picture below ([ggplot2 multiple sub groups of a bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060949/ggplot2-multiple-sub-groups-of-a-bar-chart)). However, I would like to do that for a combination of plots.

[image]

When I tried to do that, instead of having the categories clearly separated (like in the example with Irrigated/Dry and Variety1/Variety 2), my variables "growth" and "year" are being collapsed together.

I am having trouble incorporating into my code this tiny modification. I would like for my variable year to be just like "Irrigated/Dry", and the variable growth as "Variety1/Variety2" Right now, this is how the plot looks like:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)

#Creates the data

d <- expand.grid(c(.3, .8), c(.3, 0.8), c(0, 0.5), c(1, 2), c("Oregon"," California"), c("2010","2011"))
colnames(d) <- c("gamma1", "gamma2", "growth",  "store", "state", "year")
d$sells <- rnorm(64)

d$gamma_plot <- as.factor(paste(d$gamma1, d$gamma2, sep = "_"))
d$store <- as.factor(d$store)

d$growth <- factor(d$growth)
d$gamma_plot = factor(d$gamma_plot,
                              labels=c(expression(paste(gamma[1],"=", gamma[2]," = 0.3")),
                                       expression(paste(gamma[1], " = 0.3 ", gamma[2], " = 0.8")),
                                       expression(paste(gamma[1], " = 0.8 ", gamma[2], " = 0.3")),
                                       expression(paste(gamma[1],"=", gamma[2]," = 0.8"))
                              )
)

d$store = factor(d$store,
                          labels = c(expression(paste(store[1], " = 1")),
                                     expression(paste(store[2], " = 2"))
                          )
)

#Creates the plot
p = ggplot(data=d, aes(x=interaction(year, growth), y=sells, fill=state)) + 
  geom_col(position="dodge") +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_grid(store ~ gamma_plot, labeller = label_parsed) + 
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position="bottom",
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        legend.key.size = unit(0.10, "cm"),
        legend.key.width = unit(0.15,"cm")) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1)) +
  labs(x=expression(growth), y = "Sells")
```

EDITED:

The two solutions given to my question were great and I really appreciate it.
I have decided to alter the plot a little and have an interaction between gamma_plot and growth instead. I could not make R understand that gamma_plot was an expression. Any ideas?

[image]

```
#Creates the plot using teunbrand's code :)

ggplot(data=d, aes(x=interaction(growth, gamma_plot, sep = "&"), y=sells, fill=year)) + 
  geom_col(position="dodge") +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_grid(store ~ state, labeller = label_parsed) + 
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position="bottom",
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        legend.key.size = unit(0.10, "cm"),
        legend.key.width = unit(0.15,"cm"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(2,2,2,2))) +
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis_nested(delim = "&")) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1)) +
  labs(x=expression(growth), y = "Sells")
```

Comment: Is you code missing `data_plot`?

Comment: So sorry. Just fix it.

Comment: For nested axis labels see [ggplot2 multiple sub groups of a bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060949/ggplot2-multiple-sub-groups-of-a-bar-chart) (does the figure look familiar?); [Multi-row x-axis labels in ggplot line chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20571306/multi-row-x-axis-labels-in-ggplot-line-chart); [Axis labels on two lines with nested x variables (year below months)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44616530/axis-labels-on-two-lines-with-nested-x-variables-year-below-months)

Comment: Yes, I tried to use the code in that post, but that did not work for me with the combination of plots.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware there is no axis hierarchy in ggplot2. Normally, one would use facets to seperate the `year` from `growth`, but it seems like you're already using the facets to seperate out something else.

Example how one would use facets in this case:

```
ggplot(data=d, aes(x=interaction(growth), y=sells, fill=state)) + 
  geom_col(position="dodge") +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_grid(store ~ gamma_plot + year, labeller = label_parsed, switch = "x") + 
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position="bottom",
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        strip.placement = "outside",
        legend.key.size = unit(0.10, "cm"),
        legend.key.width = unit(0.15,"cm")) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1)) +
  labs(x=expression(growth), y = "Sells")
```

[image]

Seeing as the above is not really a good option, I recommend looking for extention packages that offer what you seek. If you'll allow me to be so bold, there is a function in a github package I wrote that formats axes in a nested fashion. Example below:

```
library(ggh4x)
ggplot(data=d, aes(x=interaction(growth, year, sep = "&"), y=sells, fill=state)) + 
  geom_col(position="dodge") +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_grid(store ~ gamma_plot, labeller = label_parsed) + 
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position="bottom",
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        legend.key.size = unit(0.10, "cm"),
        legend.key.width = unit(0.15,"cm"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(2,2,2,2))) +
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis_nested(delim = "&")) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1)) +
  labs(x=expression(growth), y = "Sells")
```

[image]

Edit:
With regards to the follow up question about the spacing between years; I can't think of an elegant solution but the following would get the job done. It converts the discrete axis to a continuous one.

```
# Precalculate interaction
d$interaction <- interaction(d$growth, d$year, sep = "&")
nudge <- 1 # How much you want to nudge

# Use ifelse to nudge position and use factor as integer
ggplot(data=d, aes(x=ifelse(as.numeric(interaction) > 2, 
                            as.numeric(interaction) + nudge, 
                            as.numeric(interaction)),
                   y=sells, fill=state)) + 
  geom_col(position="dodge") +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_grid(store ~ gamma_plot, labeller = label_parsed) + 
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position="bottom",
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        legend.key.size = unit(0.10, "cm"),
        legend.key.width = unit(0.15,"cm"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(2,2,2,2))) +
  # Using a continuous axis here
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1,2,3 + nudge, 4 + nudge),
                     labels = levels(d$interaction),
                     guide = guide_axis_nested(delim = "&")) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1)) +
  labs(x=expression(growth), y = "Sells")
```

[image]

Comment: Great, that worked perfectly! Just a follow-up question: would it be possible to add more horizontal spacing/padding between the years within each plot? In a way that the bars for 2010 and the bars for 2011 are more distinguishable?

Comment: Yes but couldn't come up with an elegant solution. See edit above

Comment: The solution was great. I decided to change the plot's organization and now I am having trouble making ggplot2 understand that one of the labels is an expression. Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

How about this option:

```r
library(ggplot2)


ggplot(data=d, aes(x = interaction(year, growth), y=sells, fill = state)) + 
  geom_col(position="dodge") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = unique(interaction(d$year, factor(d$growth), sep = "\n")))+
  theme_bw() +
  facet_grid(store ~ gamma_plot, labeller = label_parsed) + 
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position="bottom",
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        legend.key.size = unit(0.10, "cm"),
        legend.key.width = unit(0.15,"cm")) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1)) +
  labs(x = expression(Year~growth), y = "Sells")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>