# Barchart with groups and supergroups?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm trying to build a ggolot barchart in which bars are grouped on **several levels of grouping**.

See the following chart (built with excel) for the desired result (please note the x-axis grouping):

[image]

Is it possible to use ggplot (or any other plotting package) to produce such a chart?

Comment: mega group is facet, read about facet_grid facet_wrap, and normal groups are done by `geom_bar(position = "dodge")`

Comment: Related: [ggplot2 multiple sub groups of a bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060949/ggplot2-multiple-sub-groups-of-a-bar-chart) or [Multirow axis labels with nested grouping variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165863/multirow-axis-labels-with-nested-grouping-variables)

Comment: Also it is always helpful to share some reproducible data using `dput`?