# Multi-row x-axis labels in ggplot line chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Edit:** This question has been marked as duplicated, but the responses [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165863/ggplot2-labels-of-grouping-values-below-the-plot) have been tried and did not work because the case in question is a line chart, not a bar chart. Applying those methods produces a chart with 5 lines, 1 for each year - not useful. Did anyone who voted to mark as duplicate actually try those approaches on the sample dataset supplied with this question? If so please post as an answer.

**Original Question:**

There's a feature in Excel pivot charts which allows multilevel categorical axes.I'm trying to find a way to do the same thing with `ggplot` (or any other plotting package in R).

Consider the following dataset:

```
set.seed(1)
df=data.frame(year=rep(2009:2013,each=4),
              quarter=rep(c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4"),5),
              sales=40:59+rnorm(20,sd=5))
```

If this is imported to an Excel pivot table, it is straightforward to create the following chart:

[image]

Note how the x-axis has two levels, one for quarter and one for the grouping variable, year. Are multilevel axes possible with `ggplot`?

NB: There is a hack with facets that produces something similar, but this is not what I'm looking for.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) +
  geom_line(aes(x=quarter,y=sales,group=year))+
  facet_grid(.~year,scales="free")
```

[image]

Answer (score 84, accepted):

New labels are added using `annotate(geom = "text",`. Turn off clipping of x axis labels with `clip = "off"` in `coord_cartesian`.

Use `theme` to add extra margins (`plot.margin`) and remove (`element_blank()`) x axis text (`axis.title.x`, `axis.text.x`) and vertical grid lines (`panel.grid.x`).

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = interaction(year, quarter, lex.order = TRUE), 
                      y = sales, group = 1)) +
  geom_line(colour = "blue") +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = seq_len(nrow(df)), y = 34, label = df$quarter, size = 4) +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 2.5 + 4 * (0:4), y = 32, label = unique(df$year), size = 6) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(35, 65), expand = FALSE, clip = "off") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 4, 1), "lines"),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

---

See also the nice answer by @eipi10 here: [Axis labels on two lines with nested x variables (year below months)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44616530/axis-labels-on-two-lines-with-nested-x-variables-year-below-months)

Comment: @Henrik How would I do this if I had months instead of quarters in the data as in `quarter=rep(c("Jan","Feb","Mar","May"),5)` ?

Comment: Is there a way to dodge overlapping labels on the (new) top axis? My versions of Q1, Q2, etc. are a bit lengthy. Normally I would use scale_x_discrete and dodge, but that doesn't work because these new axes aren't technically considered axes.

Comment: @pfadenhw Not very pretty, but perhaps add/subtract a small offset to every second `y` value, e.g. `y = 34 + rep(0:-1, nrow(df) / 2)`. You may need to adjust `y` for the second row labels accordingly as well. Otherwise, I would try the `facet` alternatives in the answer I linked to - then you should be able to use [`guide_axis`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/guide_axis.html) and its `n.dodge` argument. Good luck!

Answer (score 38):

The suggested code by Henrik does work and helped me a lot! I think the solution has a high value. But please be aware, that there is a small misstake in the first line of the code, which results in a wrong order of the data. 
Instead of

```
... aes(x = interaction(year,quarter), ...
```

it should be

```
... aes(x = interaction(quarter,year), ...
```

The resulting graphic has the data in the right order.

[image]

P.S. I suggested an edit (which was rejected until now) and, due to a small lack of reputation, I am not allowed to comment, what I rather would have done.

Answer (score 15):

User `Tung` had a great answer [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52554822/save-a-ggplot2-time-series-plot-grob-generated-by-ggplotgrob)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(scales)

set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(
  date = as.Date(41000:42000, origin = "1899-12-30"), 
  value = c(rnorm(500, 5), rnorm(501, 10))
)

# create year column for facet
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(year = as.factor(year(date)))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(date, value)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(df$date[yday(df$date) == 1]), color = "grey60") + 
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b", 
               breaks = pretty_breaks(),
               expand = c(0, 0)) +
  # switch the facet strip label to the bottom
  facet_grid(.~ year, space = 'free_x', scales = 'free_x', switch = 'x') +
  labs(x = "") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 14, base_family = 'mono') +
  theme(panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank()) + 
  # remove facet spacing on x-direction
  theme(panel.spacing.x = unit(0,"line")) +
  # switch the facet strip label to outside 
  # remove background color
  theme(strip.placement = 'outside',
        strip.background.x = element_blank())
p
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Late in the game, here another approach, with the new-ish ggh4x package.

```r
library(ggh4x)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_line(aes(x = interaction(quarter, year), y = sales, group = 1))+
  scale_x_discrete(NULL, guide = "axis_nested")
```

[image]