# Two lines of X axis labels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I want to make two lines of X axis labels in ggplot.

[image]

In this plot, I want to add one more line of label below each specified year. Something like

`1990 1995 2000 2005 2010
 cold warm warm cold warm`

This is my code for making this plot

```
ggplot(subset(dat, countryid %in% c("1")),  aes(date, 
nonpartisan))+geom_line(aes(color=countryid), color="dodgerblue1", 
size=1.4)+geom_line(aes(date, reshuffle), color="gray")+ theme_bw()
```

Is there any way to make one more line of label by creating a column specifically for the labels?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multi-row x-axis labels in ggplot line chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20571306/multi-row-x-axis-labels-in-ggplot-line-chart)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can just add custom labels via `scale_x_continuous` (or `scale_x_date`, if it is actually in `Date` format).

```
ggplot(subset(dat, countryid %in% c("1")),  aes(date, nonpartisan)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=countryid), color="dodgerblue1", size=1.4) +
  geom_line(aes(date, reshuffle), color="gray") + 
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_continuous(name = 'date', 
                     breaks = c('1990', '1995', '2000', '2005', '2010'), 
                     labels = c('1990\ncold', '1995\nwarm', '2000\nwarm', '2005\ncold', '2010\nwarm'))
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. I only modified your code from `scale_x_continuous` to `scale_x_date`. Minor modifications for the breaks as well.

Comment: @user3077008 could you post your resulting code? thanks