# how to add two Column on ggplot bar chart

Tags: python, ggplot2, python-ggplot

in Excel you can draw something like this. does anybody know how to do it in qqplot

[image]

and Excel generate Graph like this.

[image]

what i am looking for is read circle thing? does is possible to do it in ggplot?

Comment: Found the answer here : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20571306/multi-row-x-axis-labels-in-ggplot-line-chart

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried facet_wrap or facet_grid?
http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/facet_wrap.html

Comment: facet_wrap create multiple graphs which was closest solution but i found exact solution what i was looking for. See below Answer.