# Double index/category bar plot in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, dplyr, visualization

Given the df:

```
col1  col2   n
aaa   login  5
aaa   tran   100 
bbb   login  23123
bbb   regis  45
bbb   tran   4
```

I want to build a `ggplot` grouped by `col1` that will show a `bar plot` for each `col2` it's `n` value.

I have tried to do this with `interaction` but it's not what I want.

Here is the scheme of the graph I need:

[image]

Comment: Try `barplot(xtabs(n ~ col1 + col2, df))`

Comment: In your `aes`, set x to `col1` and fill to `col2`. Or use facets to create panels by `col1` and put `col2` on the x-axis. But +1 for including a sketch when you don't already have a plot to show

Comment: For the facetted approach: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20571306/5325862

Comment: Please post as answers so I could accept :)