# Ggplot grouped column chart with two sets of x labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataset which produces a grouped bar plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
expand.grid(gender=c("M","F"), 
            education=c("HS","College","Advanced"), 
            value = sample(1:20,8, replace = T)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x =  education, y = value, fill = gender))+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

But instead of having a legend I want the labels to be on the x axis like this:

[image]

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Make education level the facetting variable and gender the x variable (optionally also the fill variable). Adjust the theme to put the facet labels at the bottom if that's where you want them. Similar to here https://stackoverflow.com/q/20571306/5325862

Answer (score 0):

as camille already mentioned in a comment, you can use `facet_wrap`

```
expand.grid(gender=c("M","F"), 
        education=c("HS","College","Advanced"), 
        value = sample(1:20,8, replace = T)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x =  gender, y = value, fill = gender))+
geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
facet_wrap(~education)
```

The resulting plot looks like this:

[image: resulting plot]

If you want to remove the legend, just add `theme(legend.position="none")`