# Separate y-axis labels by facet OR remove legend but keep the space

Tags: r, ggplot2

Ok, I'm stumped on a home-brew ggplot.

What I would like to do is have a three row, one column faceted plot with a different y-axis *label* for each facet. The units of the y-axis are all the same. This would be the most convenient, but googling tells me it may not be possible.

Alternatively, I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/0gRO0Pkd6Yo) solution using grid.arrange, which seems like it will work. However, I want to keep a legend only for one plot and remove it from the other two, but maintain the spacing as if it were still there so that everything lines up nice. Someone had the [same problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/qDgMsaPkhCE) a few years ago, but the suggested solution is depreciated and I can't sort out how to make it work in modern ggplot.

Any help is appreciated! Using facets would be easiest!

Edited to add copy of plot after using user20560's gridArrange solution below. Very nearly there, just would like to get back the box around the top and bottom facet panels!

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have assumed (possibly wrongly) that you are wanting to add separate y-axis titles rather than axis labels. [If it is the labels you want different you can use the `scales` argument in `facet_grid`]

There will be a ***ggplot*** way to do this but here are a couple of ways you could tweak the grobs yourself.

So using **mtcars** dataset as example

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
```

One way

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, col=factor(vs))) +   geom_point() + 
                                 facet_grid(gear ~ .)

# change the y axis labels manually
g <- ggplotGrob(p)
yax <- which(g$layout$name=="ylab")

# define y-axis labels
g[["grobs"]][[yax]]$label <- c("aa","bb", "cc")

# position of labels (ive just manually specified)
g[["grobs"]][[yax]]$y <- grid::unit(seq(0.15, 0.85, length=3),"npc")

grid::grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Or using `grid.arrange`

```
# Create a plot for each level of grouping variable and y-axis label
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars[mtcars$gear==3, ], aes(mpg, wt, col=factor(vs))) + 
                                 geom_point() + labs(y="aa") + theme_bw()
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars[mtcars$gear==4, ], aes(mpg, wt, col=factor(vs))) +  
                                 geom_point() + labs(y="bb") + theme_bw()
p3 <- ggplot(mtcars[mtcars$gear==5, ], aes(mpg, wt, col=factor(vs))) +  
                                 geom_point() + labs(y="cc") + theme_bw()

# remove legends from two of the plots
g1 <- ggplotGrob(p1)
g1[["grobs"]][[which(g1$layout$name=="guide-box")]][["grobs"]] <- NULL

g3 <- ggplotGrob(p3)
g3[["grobs"]][[which(g3$layout$name=="guide-box")]][["grobs"]] <- NULL

gridExtra::grid.arrange(g1,p2,g3)
```

If it is the axis titles you want to add I should ask *why* you want a different titles - can the facet strip text not do?

Comment: It is indeed axis titles I'm after. I hadn't thought of the (obvious) answer of just using the facet strip text, but I think it is cleaner and more standard to have the titles by the axis labels since they are actually describing the units (the units all three plots are mm but they are mm of different things). Your above solution using grid arrange works well except that it also removes the box around each facet panel. I'm not very grob savvy, so I'm not sure what to do about it. I'll try and add a copy of the plot in here somewhere....

Comment: @IcebergSlim; You can alter the thickness of the `panel.border`. For example, using the plot p3 above: `p3 + theme_bw() + theme(panel.border=element_rect(fill=NA, colour = "black", size=2))`, although perhaps just `theme_bw()` is enough. You may also find it useful to change the theme `plot.margin` to control the space between the arranged plots.

Comment: Hmm....panel border doesn't do much for me. The borders display correctly until I get in there and manipulate the grob. I'm not sure why changing the guide box would affect the plot border. Maybe I'm moving into bug territory here. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @IcebergSlim; sorry mistake in the answer code  - i was missing a `[["grobs"]]` - corrected - seems ok now

Comment: Yup, that did it, really hammering home the fact that I don't know anything about grobs. Thanks for the followups.

Comment: I am trying to use the first method, but I don't have a `ylab` in `g$layout$name` , insted i have `ylab-r` and `ylab-l`. I guess it means `ylab` on right and left side respectively. I tried to change one of them as well as both of them to the labels I want. But nothing works. Can you help me?

Comment: @user3420448 ; seems this doesnt work any more due to the several significant rewrites of ggplot2 which have changed the internal plot object structure. These sort of answers have proven to be quite unstable. Some of the other answers may be able to help / provide an alt approach.

Answer (score 4):

Following the comments by Axeman and aosmith (thank you), here's a way to do this using the facet labels using ggplot2 version 2.2.0

```
library(ggplot2) # From sessionInfo(): ggplot2_2.2.0

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, col=factor(vs))) + geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(gear ~ ., switch = 'y') +
  theme( axis.title.y = element_blank(), # remove the default y-axis title, "wt"
         strip.background = element_rect(fill = 'transparent'), # replace the strip backgrounds with transparent
         strip.placement = 'outside', # put the facet strips on the outside
         strip.text.y = element_text(angle=180)) # rotate the y-axis text (optional)
# (see ?ggplot2::theme for a list of theme elements (args to theme()))
```

Comment: Sounds like you want `switch.placement = "outside"` for ggplot2_2.2.0.  See answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36337286/2461552) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but after finding it, I could not get @user20560's response to work.

I've edited @user20560's `grid.extra` approach as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)

# Create a plot for each level of grouping variable and y-axis label
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars[mtcars$gear==3, ], aes(mpg, wt, col=factor(vs))) + 
  geom_point() + labs(y="aa") + theme_bw()
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars[mtcars$gear==4, ], aes(mpg, wt, col=factor(vs))) +  
  geom_point() + labs(y="bb") + theme_bw()
p3 <- ggplot(mtcars[mtcars$gear==5, ], aes(mpg, wt, col=factor(vs))) +  
  geom_point() + labs(y="cc") + theme_bw()

# get the legend as a grob
legend <- ggplotGrob(p1)
legend <- legend$grobs[[which(legend$layout$name=="guide-box")]]
lheight <- sum(legend$height)
lwidth <- sum(legend$width)

# remove the legend from all the plots
p1 <- p1 + theme(legend.position = 'none')
p2 <- p2 + theme(legend.position = 'none')
p3 <- p3 + theme(legend.position = 'none')

# force the layout to the right side
layoutMat <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,4,4),ncol = 2)

grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3,legend, layout_matrix = layoutMat, ncol = 2, 
             widths = grid::unit.c(unit(1,'npc') - lwidth, lwidth))
```

This example is somewhat specific to this particular layout. There is a more general approach on the `ggplot2` [wiki](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Share-a-legend-between-two-ggplot2-graphs).

Comment: These have different x-axes.  I believe the OP wanted three plots that shared the x-axis, but had different y-axes.

Comment: Based on OP's last edit the picture showed different x-axes. If you want to share x-axes, then you can use `facet_grid` as shown in @Richard DiSalvo's response below.

Answer (score 1):

I too had trouble getting the first approach in [the answer of user20560](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23750773/239838) (above) to work. This is probably because the internals of ggplot2 have evolved, and there is no guarantee that these internals should stay the same.  In any case, here is a version that currently works:

```
library(ggplot2) # From sessionInfo(): ggplot2_2.1.0
library(grid)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, col=factor(vs))) + geom_point() + facet_grid(gear ~ .)
g <- ggplotGrob(p)
yax <- which(g$layout$name == "ylab")
g[["grobs"]][[yax]]$children[[1]]$label <- c('fo','bar','foobar')
g[["grobs"]][[yax]]$children[[1]]$y <- grid::unit(seq(0.15, 0.85, length=3), "npc")
grid.draw(g)
```

Note that this is the approach that keeps the facets and does not repeat the x-axes.

Comment: A good way to do this with the current `ggplot2` version is to use `switch = 'y'` in `facet_grid`, and then use theme settings to remove the y axis labels and strip background. No `grid` manipulation necessary.