# How to group bars arbitrarily in ggplot

Tags: r, excel, ggplot2

I want to know if it's feasible to create a bar chart with groupings by type in ggplot the same way I would in excel. I have the following data:

```
 df <- data.frame(label = c("A", "A", "B", "C"), variable = c("alpha", "beta", "tim", "tom"), values = c(1,2,4,1))
```

In excel, I can easily create a graph that looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do something similar in ggplot, where the column 'label' groups the variables?

Comment: Not sure if you are looking for only exactly the same kind of plot. In ggplot2, you could also do `ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = values, fill = label)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")` which would fill the bars with colors according to their labels and put the color codes in a legend at the right.

Comment: Yeah, that won't work for me because I actually have like 50 variables, and I don't want to have to read off the legend.

Comment: Ok, I see. It seems that the answer by @jed might be just what you're after then.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ggplot2 - labels of grouping values below the plot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165863/ggplot2-labels-of-grouping-values-below-the-plot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use facet_grid and set the `scales = "free_x"` and `space = "free"`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(variable, values)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + facet_grid(~ label, scales = "free_x", space = "free")
```

[image]