# Add grouping in ggplot2 heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

Hello I have the dataset below:

```
gene_symbol <- c("DADA", "SDAASD", "SADDSD", "SDADD")
panel <- c("growth", "growth", "big", "small")
ASDDA <- c("normal", "over", "low", "over")
ASDDb <- c("normal", "over", "low", "over")
ASDDAf <- c("normal", "over", "low", "over")
Gene_states22 <- data.frame(gene_symbol, panel, ASDDA, ASDDb, ASDDAf)
```

What I want to achieve besides creating a heatmap with:

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2); library(reshape2)
g <- melt(Gene_states22, id.vars = c("gene_symbol","panel"))
p1 <- ggplot(g, aes(gene_symbol,variable)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value), colour = "grey50") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("white", "red", "blue"))+
  labs(title = "Heatmap",x = "gene_symbol",y="sample",fill="value")+
  theme(title = element_text(family = "sans serif", 
                             size = 14, 
                             face = "bold"), 
        axis.title = element_text(family = "sans serif", 
                                  size = 16, 
                                  face = "bold", 
                                  color = "black"), 
        axis.text = element_text(family = "sans serif", 
                                 size = 11),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 25, b = 0, l = 25)),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey50"))
p1
ggplotly(p1)%>%
  layout(autosize = F, 
         width = 1450, 
         height = 600,
         hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "white",
                           font = list(family = "sans serif", 
                                       size = 9, 
                                       color = "black")))
```

is group my values according to `panel`. For example:
[image]

here there is a second x-axis which groups the values by "Mechanical","Electrical","Hydraylic". I want to do the same with the `panel`. Note that the graph should be interactive and this is why I use `ggplotly()`

I managed to use @aosmith answer but the result is a little bit ugly
[image]

Comment: Maybe something along [these lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36337286/2461552)?

Comment: useful but I cannot implement it appropriately

Comment: Is the ultimate goal here a static plot (using `ggplot2`), or an interactive one (using `plotly`)? Some ggplot elements aren't preserved appropriately when converting from one to the other, so solutions for the former may not always work.

Comment: My goal is to create an interactive plot using ggplotly. I also updated the question

Comment: I implemented aosmith answer but the result is little bit strange as you can see in my edit.