# ggplot2 for bar plot with two same tick labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a dataset like:

Date    Value   Label

2016/01   2        A

2016/02   3        A

2016/03   4        A

2016/04   5        A

2016/05   4        A

2016/05   4        B

2016/06   5        B

2016/07   6        B

The date "2016/05" appears two times in my dataset. I want to use ggplot2 to generate bar plot. How to make the bar plot have two same tick labels?

The target figure is like this:
[image: Sample Image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165863/multirow-axis-labels-with-nested-grouping-variables

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a new `ID` column so that you have unique categories on the x-axis:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(Date = c("2016/01", "2016/02", "2016/03", "2016/04", 
                              "2016/05", "2016/05", "2016/06", "2016/07"), 
                     Value = c(2L, 3L,4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L), 
                     Label = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B")), .Names = c("Date", "Value", "Label"), 
                row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df %>%
  unite(ID, Date, Label) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(ID, Value)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Alternatively you could use the `Label` column to facet the data like so:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Date, Value)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(.~Label, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I prefer the second plot.  However, when I run the code, there is an  error!

Comment: df <- structure(list(Date = c("2016/01", "2016/02", "2016/03", "2016/04", 
                              "2016/05", "2016/05", "2016/06", "2016/07"), 
                     Value = c(2L, 3L,4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L), 
                     Label = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B")), .Names = c("Date", "Value", "Label"), 
                row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Date, Value)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(.~Label, scales = "free_x")

Comment: ERROR while rich displaying an object: Error in combine_vars(data, params$plot_env, vars, drop = params$drop): At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting

Comment: The code works fine for me. Try removing the period from the facet argument `facet_wrap(~Label, scales = "free_x")`