# Group bar plot based on more than 1 variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Im trying to group bars in R to have them based on two variables, `type` (Tax, income and VAT) and `group` (A and B).
I succeeded to group based on the type, however when I´m trying to group it seem not to work.

```
plot <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Person, y=Amount, fill=FIAT ))+
  geom_bar(aes(), stat="identity", position="fill")+ 
  facet_grid(~type, scales="free_x")
```

The outcome I receive is this:

[image: Plot bar with type-variable]

The wanted outcome should look something like this, with group in the bottom:

[image: Wanted plot bar]

The output from dput:

```
dput(head(df.new))
structure(list(Person = c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Tina", 
"lisa"), Amount = c(23, 41, 32, 58, 26, 54), type = c("Tax", 
"Tax", "VAT", "Income", "Tax", "Income"), group = c("A", "B", 
"B", "A", "B", "A"), FIAT = c("BTC", "GBP", "BTC", "EURO", "USD", 
"USD")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: can you `dput(head(df))` that would be helpful

Comment: `facet_grid(group~type, scales="free_x")` or adding `group = group` in `aes()` might help

Comment: Another solution could be to create a variable `type_group` with the 6 categories

Comment: @PesKchan I´ve added the output from dput now.

Comment: Where is your `FIAT` column?

Comment: Sorry, added wrong dataframe.

Comment: @L-- The first suggestion made two column, the upper one with `A` and the lower one with `B` instead of having the bars in the same plot. 
The other suggestion did not work, I tried to add it in aes() of `geom_bar(aes(), stat="identity", position="fill")`

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165863/multirow-axis-labels-with-nested-grouping-variables

Answer (score 1):

I see two options, both with the {ggh4x} package. I'd personally prefer the facet_nested approach, as easier to code, looks neater, and also no warning (which I don't know where it's coming from, I assume from the unique group and absence of all levels in your last facet), but there is - to my knowledge - no easy way to switch the side from the nested strips only. This can of course be achieved but would (IMO) require some grob hacking.

**Option 1 - facet_nested**

```r
library(ggh4x)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Person, y=Amount, fill=FIAT ))+
  geom_bar(aes(), stat="identity", position="fill")+ 
  facet_nested(~ type + group, scales="free_x")
```

[image]

**Option 2 - guide_axis_nested**

```r
## make a combined group from your x Person and group
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=interaction(Person, group, sep = "&"), y=Amount, fill=FIAT ))+
  geom_bar(aes(), stat="identity", position="fill")+ 
  facet_grid(~ type, scales="free_x") +
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis_nested(delim = "&"), name = NULL)
#> Warning in min(diff(position)): no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>