# ggh4x: Grouping Sub-Groups together in Faceted Plots with guide_nested_axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggh4x

I would like to create a bar plot in which the discrete values of the x axis would be grouped into subgroups (see code below), when I have already faceted on another variable. I have used ggh4x to get me close. But I'm not quite there:

```
set.seed(9) 
dfx <- data.frame(
    x = rep(LETTERS[1:2], 50),
    Group = rep(c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3"), c(33, 33, 34)),
    value = rpois(100, 10),
    facet_var = sample(rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"),c(25,25,25,25)))
)

ggplot(dfx, aes(paste0(x, "&", Group), value)) +
    geom_col() +
    facet_wrap( ~ facet_var, ncol=2) +
    guides(x = ggh4x::guide_axis_nested(delim = "&"))
```

[image]

But would like it to group my "Group" column together so that it looks more like what I see in this example:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = LETTERS[1:16],
  group = rep(c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3"), c(5, 3, 8)),
  value = rpois(16, 10)
)

ggplot(df, aes(paste0(x, "&", group), value)) +
  geom_col() +
  guides(x = ggh4x::guide_axis_nested(delim = "&"))
```

[image]

Anyone can help?

Comment: related and weirdly only asked very recently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75801499/group-bar-plot-based-on-more-than-1-variable

Comment: Interesting! I did a pretty deep search before posting. I think that didn't come up because it was barplot specific, and while what I am showing is a barplot, I wanted this as a generic solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `interaction` instead of `paste`.

```r
library(ggh4x)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
set.seed(9) 
dfx <- data.frame(
  x = rep(LETTERS[1:2], 50),
  Group = rep(c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3"), c(33, 33, 34)),
  value = rpois(100, 10),
  facet_var = sample(rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"),c(25,25,25,25)))
)

ggplot(dfx, aes(interaction(x, Group, sep = "&"), value)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap( ~ facet_var, ncol=2) +
  guides(x = ggh4x::guide_axis_nested(delim = "&"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Fantastic, this also solves a follow on where I wanted to change the order of the "x" variable when I had a large number of them (rather than just A & B) the interaction function follows my "factor" ordering. Fantastic answer, if I could up-vote it more I would.