# Multirow y-axis labels with nested grouping variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like the levels of two different nested grouping variables to appear on separate lines in the y-axis of the plot, and not in the legend. What I have right now is this code:

```
data <- tibble::tribble(                       ~ term,   ~estimate, ~conf.low, ~conf.high,           ~group,           
"HH cultivated plots",                                         0.0163,  -0.0130,    0.0456, "Extensive Margin",
"# of farm assets (hoe, spade, axe), all HHs",                 0.356,    0.143,     0.569,  "Assets",          
"Number of plots",                                            -0.0539,  -0.158,     0.0498, "Intensive Margin",
"Farm size",                                                   0.208,   -0.0394,    0.456,  "Intensive Margin",
"# of HH members that cultivated plots, all HHs",              0.0541,  -0.0647,    0.173,  "Intensive Margin",
"Avg # of days HH members spent cultivating plots, all HHs",  -0.192,   -0.738,     0.354,  "Intensive Margin",
"Annual agricultural revenue",                                 0.329,    0.170,     0.487,  "Revenue")

ag_coef_plot <- data %>%
  
  ggplot(
    
    aes(x =  estimate, 
        y = term,
        color = group
    
  )) +
  
  geom_pointrange( # Confidence interval
    
    aes(
      xmin = conf.low, 
      xmax = conf.high
    ), 
    
    show.legend = FALSE,
    
  ) +
  
  scale_x_continuous(name = "") +
  
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  
  scale_y_discrete(name = "", 
                   limits = rev, 
                   expand = c(.05, 0)) + 
  
  theme_minimal() + 
  
  theme(
    
    plot.title          = element_text(size = 15, hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"),
    
    plot.title.position = "plot",
    
    plot.background     = element_rect(color = "black"), # For some reason this is necessary to ensure background color ISN'T black. Go figure
    
    axis.text.y         =  element_text(size = 15),
    
    axis.text.x         =  element_text(size = 15),
    
    legend.position     = "left",
    
    legend.title        = element_blank(),
    
    legend.text         = element_blank()
    
    
  ) +
  
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set2") 

ag_coef_plot
```

This code produces this plot:

[image]

But I want to achieve something like this, and in the perfect scenario with the group label in the same colors as the points:

[image]

I have tried solutions from this post but I cannot make it work: [Multirow axis labels with nested grouping variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165863/multirow-axis-labels-with-nested-grouping-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertical lines you have between the grouping variables don't correspond to any theme elements in ggplot, but if you are happy with simple boxes, you can achieve the rest with ggplot and ggtext:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtext)
library(RColorBrewer)

data %>%
  mutate(
    group = gsub(" ", "<br>", group),
    color =  brewer.pal(4, "Set2")[match(group, levels(factor(group)))],
    name = glue::glue("<i style='color:{color}'>{group}</i>"),
    name = fct_reorder(name, as.numeric(factor(group)))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(estimate, term, color = group)) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(xmin = conf.low, xmax = conf.high), show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  labs(x = NULL) +
  scale_y_discrete(NULL, limits = rev) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
  facet_grid(name ~ ., scales = "free_y", switch = "y", space = "free_y") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 15) + 
  theme(strip.placement     = "outside",
        strip.text.y.left   = element_markdown(size = 15, angle = 0,
                                               margin = margin(10, 10, 10, 10)),
        panel.spacing.y     = unit(0, "mm"),
        strip.background    = element_rect()
  )
```

[image]